# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object references [pls help me]

Tags: java, android-studio

i have checked thrice i am sure all id is correct , but still there is some mistake

i am trying to get title, image and description to second activity but it says

> void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

i am able to get title, image and description to first activity but when i am trying to get in another its says on a null object :(

Can anyone help me pls whats wrong i'm doing here

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/reycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```

**animal_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AnimalActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/animal_item_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**animal_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/animallayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animal_logo"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/animals" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/animal_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Story Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/animal_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Story Description"
            android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

**book_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_logo_img"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/animals" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/story_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Story Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/story_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Story Description"
            android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Story_Details> story_details;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reycler_view);

    story_details = new ArrayList<>();
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
    RecylerViewAdapter recylerViewAdapter = new RecylerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,story_details);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recylerViewAdapter);

}
```

}

**AnimalActitivy.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Story_Details> story_details;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reycler_view);

    story_details = new ArrayList<>();
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));
    story_details.add(new Story_Details("Animal","All About Animal stories ",R.drawable.animals));


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
    RecylerViewAdapter recylerViewAdapter = new RecylerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,story_details);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recylerViewAdapter);

}
```

}

**Animal_Item_Adapter**

```
public class Animal_item_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Animal_item_adapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Animal_details> animal_details;


public Animal_item_adapter(Context mContext, List<Animal_details> animal_details) {
    this.context = mContext;
    this.animal_details = animal_details;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Animal_item_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.book_activity,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.animal_logo.setImageResource(animal_details.get(position).getThumb());
    holder.animal_title.setText(animal_details.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.animal_description.setText(animal_details.get(position).getDescription());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return animal_details.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView animal_logo;
    private TextView animal_title , animal_description;
    private LinearLayout animallayout;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        animal_logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal_logo);

        animal_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal_title);

        animal_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal_description);

        animallayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.animallayout);


    }

}
```

}

**Recyler_View_Adapter**

```
public class RecylerViewAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecylerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Story_Details> story_details;
LinearLayout linearLayout;


public RecylerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Story_Details> story_details) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.story_details = story_details;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.book_activity,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.book_logo_img.setImageResource(story_details.get(position).getThumb());
    holder.story_title.setText(story_details.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.story_description.setText(story_details.get(position).getDescription());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return story_details.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView book_logo_img;
    private TextView story_title , story_description;
    private LinearLayout linear_layout;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        book_logo_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_logo_img);

        story_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.story_title);

        story_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.story_description);

        linear_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent;

                switch (getAdapterPosition()){
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AnimalActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

**Animal_details.java**

```
public class Animal_details {
private String Title;
private String Description;
private int Thumb;

public Animal_details() {
}

public Animal_details(String title, String description, int thumb) {
    Title = title;
    Description = description;
    Thumb = thumb;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public int getThumb() {
    return Thumb;
}

public void setThumb(int thumb) {
    Thumb = thumb;
}
```

}

**Story_details.java**

```
public class Story_Details {
private String Title;
private String Description;
private int Thumb;


public Story_Details() {
}

public Story_Details(String title, String description, int thumb) {
    Title = title;
    Description = description;
    Thumb = thumb;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public int getThumb() {
    return Thumb;
}

public void setThumb(int thumb) {
    Thumb = thumb;
}
```

}